# How to get certain div array elements containing a specific string in the subclass

Tags: ruby, watir

How to get each div element ID in an array and containing specific string I need in it containing in the elements subclass theText.

```
<div id="corporaContainer" class="fullList">
  <div id="c-ff7c1098-8183-4c89-b3ec-b2587aa6d372" class="resItem clearfix">
    <div class="resTitle">
      <span id="filter-ready" class="statBall statFile ready" title="Status: ready"></span>
      <span class="theText"></span>
    </div>
  <div class="resType"></div>
  <div class="resSize"></div>
  <div class="resPermission public"></div> 
  <div class="resDomain"></div>
  <div class="resDescr"></div>
  <div class="resDetails clearfix" style="display:none;"></div>
```

I tried to make an array with a loop over each ID and check .include? function.
But had no success so far.

I need the script to jump over each div element and check if it does contain the string I need, then store the elements ID value in an array to use this ID later.

Added the script code I made so far.

```
@b = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, :switches => %w[--disable-plugins --ignore-certificate-errors --disable-popup-blocking --disable-translate --disable-translate]
#-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
require_relative "1_login.rb"

# Ieiet Corpora sadaļā
@b.div(:id, "pageHeader").link(:text, "Corpora").click

lietotajs = @b.div(:class, "userRealName").text
dzesamie_korpusi = @b.div(:id, "corporaContainer", :class => "fullList")


korpusu_id = []
dzesamie_korpusi.each do |korpuss|
    id = korpuss.attribute_value "id"
    id = id[-38..-1]
    korpusu_id.push(id)
end
```

I tried so far that the script loops via each DIV element under corporacontainer and gets the div elements id to store ir in an array, but this exact code returns an error such that it is expecting Hash tag or what to do with it now.

Comment: Please provide the code that you have so far.

Comment: Added the code im using to make the script jump via each div element and get its id without specific text included.

Comment: In the code above, dzesamie_korpusi is going to be a single div element, not a collection.  You can't use .each to iterate on an element as there is nothing to iterate over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've understood that you're looking in a root `div` with `id=corporaContainer` for every `div` child nodes that contain a descendant node `span` with `class="theText"`. And you want to get the `id` of those `div` child nodes. For that, I'd use `nokogiri` that parses HTML/XML/CSS documents.

`file.html`

```
<div id="corporaContainer" class="fullList">
  <div id="c-ff7c1098-8183-4c89-b3ec-b2587aa6d372" class="resItem clearfix">
    <div class="resTitle">
      <span id="filter-ready" class="statBall statFile ready" title="Status: ready"></span>
      <span class="theText"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="resType"></div>
  <div class="resSize"></div>
  <div class="resPermission public"></div>
  <div class="resDomain"></div>
  <div class="resDescr"></div>
  <div class="resDetails clearfix" style="display:none;"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="c-e5f0fe33-06a0-4685-8fe2-f789893bd8e2" class="resItem>clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

the script

```
require 'nokogiri'

root_id = 'corporaContainer'
filter = 'theText'

File.open('file.html') do |file|
  nodes = Nokogiri::HTML(file)

  nodes.xpath("//div[@id=\"#{root_id}\"]/div").each do |node|
    puts node['id'] unless node.xpath(".//span[@class=\"#{filter}\"]").empty?
  end
end
```

As result, you have the id that you're looking for

```
c-ff7c1098-8183-4c89-b3ec-b2587aa6d372
```

Comment: Well the problem is the document. I only have the page im trying to script. And yes im looking for the ID for the div element in corporaContainer with the string in title I specifically need, so i can use the ID in the next step of the script. nokogiri i guess wont make the magic for me. Is there any other solution so that i get the ID for and div element in corporaContainer and store it for later usage in the next script step?

Comment: @EdgarsKarķis which id do you exactly need? `c-ff7c1098-8183-4c89-b3ec-b2587aa6d372`?

Comment: yes that is what i need but only for the the DIV elements who also contains the string i need ('/TestAuto\s.*/') as a criteria.

Comment: @EdgarsKarķis That `div` is it always a direct child of the `div` with `id="corporaContainer"`?

Comment: Yes always. Its like a container who contains all the div elements ( smth like a table but not a table ) Its a List of div elements with ID i need and specific string containing, in Div id="corporaContainer"

Comment: @EdgarsKarķis ok, I've updated my answer: the script and the description of what you're looking for

Comment: Thank you with this solution it helped me i managed to get what i need and now ill try to use it properly in next script step. Appreciate the answer!

Answer (score 0):

When you say 'a string' it is a little unclear where you expect this known text to appear.  If you are looking for text that is just somewhere in the div (note 'text' as in visible (usually) on the page.. not characters within an element definition or as the value for some attribute of an element)

```
browser.div(:id => "corporaContainer").divs(:text => /TestAuto\s.*/).each do |div|
  puts div.attribute_value("id")
end
```

If the known thing is a value of an attribute, and the attribute name is constant, something like the class of a span, and the span is always nested inside some predictable level of container objects below the one with the ID you want, then something like this might work (I've no easy way to test, so try for yourself and see if you get what you want)

```
browser.div(:id => "corporaContainer").spans(:class => /TestAuto\s.*/).each do |span|
  puts span.parent.parent.attribute_value("id")
end
```